# How to conditionally insert null value in insert query?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I want to make an insert query which will insert into my table even if I insert null values but i can't seem to do it.

My table is

```
elem1 Not null
elem2 Can be null
elem3 Not null
elem4 Can be null
```

The command:

```
InsertQuery(elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4);
```

or

```
InsertQuery(elem1, elem3)
```

should both work with my request, how to do it?

Something like this :

```
insert into table1
values (@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4)
where value2 and value4 IS NULL
```

But I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Perhaps if you edit your question adding your real code then you could avoid the closure for _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Answer (score 1):

Always name the insert columns in a production query. Skipping the field list is fine when you're hacking out queries in a command window, but if your code doesn't name the columns it will break if a column is added to the table.

If you know ahead of time that `elem2` and `elem4` will always be null, just insert `elem1` and `elem3`.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (elem1, elem3)
VALUES (@value1, @value3)
```

If you don't know ahead of time, insert all fields:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4)
VALUES (@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4)
```

Note that when you bind the parameters, you can use the variables for the non-null values but for the null values you have to use `DBNull.Value`:

```
if (var1 == null) {
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", DBNull.Value);
} else {
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", var1);
}
// and likewise for values 2, 3, and 4
```

You can also do this with a one-liner, though it's a bit harder to read than the `if` approach above:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", ((Object)var1) ?? DBNull.Value);
// and likewise for values 2, 3, and 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you included a c# tag, I am assuming you want code that will do that. So take a look at the best practices which are [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

the query text would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (@Variable1, @variable2, @Variable3, @variable4);
```